# How to kill a tail process that's execute using nodejs ssh2?

Tags: linux, node.js, ssh, tail

How to kill tail process that i execute in this query ?

```
var c = new Ssh2();
   c.on('connect', function() {
     console.log('Connection :: connect');
   });
   c.on('ready', function() {
     console.log('Connection :: ready');
     c.exec('tail -f test.txt', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
        console.log((extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : '')
                   + data);
    });
    stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
        c.end();
    });
     });
   });
   c.on('error', function(err) {
     console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
   });
   c.on('end', function() {
     console.log('Connection :: end');
   });
   c.on('close', function(had_error) {
     console.log('Connection :: close');
   });        
   c.connect({
     host: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 22,
     username: 'test',
     password: 'test'
   });
```

Or is there any suggestion to execute `tail -f` using nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a form like this for your command line: 'tail -f test.txt & read; kill $!'.

Then when you want to kill the process, simply `stream.write('\n');`

Comment: thanks for the idea, but instead of using `stream.write('\n');`
i use 
`c.exec("\n", function(err, stream) {
  c.end();
});`

Comment: Doing `c.exec("\n"...);` will just execute another command on the server which is unnecessary.

`stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
  c.end();
});

stream.write('\n');`

should give you the same result without executing an additional command.

Comment: just notice this solution will have problem when the connection drop. the process will still hang on the server. so currently i'm execute another `kill` process rather than just end the current cmd.

Comment: This works well and a simple solution.